# ¿Se puede consultar porqué fue rechazada una edición?

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, ediciones

Me incorporé recientemente a la comunidad (aunque me inscribí hace mucho) para ayudar con los pocos temas que están dentro de mi experiencia. Uno de ellos no es tanto la programación como el amor por la ortografía, y el etiquetado correcto de los temas.

En ese sentido, he realizado hasta este momento apenas 4 ediciones, de las cuáles 2 fueron aprobadas y dos rechazadas, pero además de que dice "reprobadas" en la traducción, pero no entiendo ¿qué es lo que reprobé?

Mi pregunta es si, de manera similar a que se puede al menos preguntar por qué se votó negativamente una respuesta, podemos tener alguna forma de retroalimentación a las ediciones, ya que ni siquiera puedo consultar si mi edición fue mejorada por quién "reprobó" mi propuesta, o al menos consultar de nuevo la pregunta para saber si al menos el reetiquetado sí pasó o no.

Para hacer un examen concreto, tengo estas dos ediciones que "reprobé":

1. https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12434

Que corresponde a esta pregunta: [¿Cómo crear un select multiple con wp_dropdown_categories en Wodpress?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/12991/c%C3%B3mo-crear-un-select-multiple-con-wp-dropdown-categories-en-wodpress/13789#13789)

La respuesta es correcta en la orientación, salvo por un parámetro menos, yo podría haber publicado una respuesta "propia" con el parámetro faltante incluido, pero sentí que esto sería robar el crédito del autor de la respuesta correcta, ya que todo lo que faltó fue incluir el enlace, y además agregué un enlace a la documentación de la función requerida.

Los usuarios Elenasys y Shaz rechazan mi edición con la misma respuesta de plantilla, indicándome que no revisaron el mérito de la edición correctamente:

> Esta edición se aparta de la intención original de la publicación.
>   Incluso aquellas ediciones que implican grandes cambios deben
>   esmerarse para preservar los objetivos del propietario de la
>   publicación.

En absoluto, de hecho solamente agrego el parámetro para que la respuesta del autor sea 100% correcta. Ahora, gracias a la falta de diligencia, tengo que agregar una respuesta propia, comentar la primer respuesta porque no me permitieron añadir una simple corrección, y comentar al OP para que vuelva a revisar la respuesta pero tomando en cuenta mi indicación.

Mucho más sencillo sería para el OP leer la respuesta editada con el parámetro faltante y no tener que rastrear entre otras respuestas y comentarios la corrección.

2. https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/12432

El usuario Juan Pinzón aprobó la edición, que fue solamente retirar una etiqueta que no correspondía: javascript, de [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/16315/c%C3%B3mo-obtener-la-url-de-las-categorias-wordpress), de nuevo el usuario Shaz me responde con un copipega:

> Esta edición no ha corregido problemas graves en la publicación - mira
>   el historial de revisiones para ver qué debería haberse cambiado.

¿Quién dijo que quería "corregir problemas graves en la publicación"? Solamente retiré la etiqueta que no correspondía: javascript. Pero lo más curioso es que aunque mi edición no corrigió "problemas graves", Shaz hizo otra edición haciendo lo mismo, quitando la misma etiqueta.

¿Entonces esa edición sí está bien porque él la hizo y se la pudo aprobar solo y la mía no aunque fue la misma contribución?

Comment: Sería bueno si agregaras las ediciones que te fueron rechazadas para una mejor evaluación como comunidad. Incluso, es probable que quienes las hayan rechazado puedan emitir su opinión al respecto aquí

Comment: Gracias por tu observación, me costó trabajo encontrarlo pero al final di con las ediciones rechazadas, lo curioso es que el editor que rechazó mi edición en una pregunta, después hace lo mismo (la misma edición, exactamente, retirando la etiqueta que no correspondía), tomando el crédio de la edición para sí mismo después de alegar que mi edición "no corregía problemas graves".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Lo que presento aquí es meramente mi opinión.

Para la 1ª hay que separar dos partes:

1. Agregar un enlace con la documentación de la función/método/framework/etc es válido. Esto es bueno porque complementa la información que se brinda en la publicación.
2. Modificar código que está en la pregunta es debatible, aunque usualmente es un **no lo modifiques, ni siquiera para "arreglarlo"**. Si modificas código de una respuesta que no es wiki, debería ser por formato (p.e. indentarlo) o algo muy puntual. Imagina que en una versión X del software/framework/etc esa función es correcta con la firma que se muestra en la publicación, pero tú que trabajas con una versión superior X+3 sabes que dicha función está depreciada o ha sufrido modificaciones, pero en el tiempo y ámbito en que la respuesta fue publicada, el código tal como está allí **funciona**, por ello se respeta lo que se ha publicado.

   En su lugar, lo usual es agregar un comentario indicando que el código posee un error e indicar dónde está (no seas un troll que quiere dárselas de sabiondo, esa gente no es bienvenida). La otra alternativa es publicar una respuesta adicional donde muestres el código corregido de acuerdo a tu criterio.

Para la 2ª, creo que el usuario @Shaz se equivocó y debió seleccionar la opción **Aprobar y editar**. De cara al futuro, si algún usuario incluye la edición dentro de sus ediciones, entonces debería respetarla y realizar las ediciones adicionales.

Comment: Pues fue algo muy puntual, solo **un** parámetro (y el enlace a la referencia). ¿Y la edición que yo hice y rechazó y luego hizo lo mismo adjudicándosela? ¿Hay manera de reportar eso como un abuso de su reputación?

Comment: @JesúsFranco por favor revisa la edición que acabo de realizar al primer parámetro.

Comment: Es decir que aunque mi edición sea válida y termine de afinar la respuesta, ¿un usuario con más reputación que *suponga* que mi respuesta *podría* no ser correcta, puede rechazarla sin contribuir al menos con una respuesta correcta él/ella misma?

Comment: Estoy diciendo que la primera no es una edición válida. La segunda sí es válida, pero la comunidad está compuesta por humanos y nos podemos equivocar. En este caso, Shaz se equivocó al rechazar tu edición, debió aceptarla y hacer su edición sobre eso.

Comment: ¿Pero por qué no es válida la primera edición? ¿Porque agrega un parámetro para que la función haga lo que el autor de la respuesta señaló como solución para el OP? ¿Porque incluye un enlace para que el OP pueda consultar la documentación? ¿Se considera aquí enlazar a documentación una mala práctica? ¿Y truncar respuestas correctas buena?

Comment: @JesúsFranco Coincido con Luiggi. Aunque tu edición sea correcta, se considera **el código es sagrado**. La respuesta puede estar equivocada, pero las opciones son comentarlo bajo la publicación o dar otra respuesta diciendo por ejemplo "*el código de X está bien pero tiene un error*". Así funciona. Considerá que aunque tengas todos los motivos para estar acertado, quizás podés equivocarte en algo.. Publicá la alternativa y que la comunidad decida por votos.

Comment: Ya, algo así como lo que me acabas de decir: jamás toques el código de otro, es mucho más claro que orientación con con *podría* o *quizás*. Gracias LuiggiMendoza y @Mariano por su orientación.

Comment: @JesúsFranco acabo de editar la respuesta para que sea más fácil de comprender. Favor de avisarme si se entiende.

Comment: Acabo de ver todo esto, ofrezco disculpas por mi error, estaré más pendiente al respecto en el futuro (inmediato), me refiero a la segunda edición.

Answer (score 1):

Complementando a la respuesta de [@LuiggiMendoza](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/773/127), quería agregar que el texto que recibís se genera usando las [las herramientas de Revisión](https://es.stackoverflow.com/review), no es que copien y peguen sin leer tu edición.

1. El primer texto, mientras revisan tu edición se genera **automáticamente** al hacer click en

   > [image: Botón Rechazar + Motivo Intención del autor]

---

2. El segundo, mientras revisan tu edición se genera **automáticamente** al hacer click en:

   > [image: Botón Rechazar y editar]

-Igual también considero que está equivocado en rechazar tu segunda edición. Estaba muy bien que hayas sacado la etiqueta [javascript](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript).

---

Es decir, no lo tomes como que no evaluaron el caso, **es la respuesta automática del sistema**...
Y, por favor ¡¡¡**seguí editando**!!!. Le hace bien al sitio que haya usuarios buscando mejorar la calidad de las publicaciones.

Comment: Pues lo entiendo, pero si con dos clicks se pueden rechazar las ediciones, sí desanima un poco y más que el aludido @Shaz ni por enterado.

Comment: Cada sugerencia de edición se tiene que evaluar exhaustivamente... Pero es humano, quizás se equivocó. Lo mismo podría pasarte cuando tengas la experiencia para hacer revisiones.

Comment: Sí, e intentaré hacer uso del trago amargo para no "reprobar" a otros usuarios cuando su colaboración sea válida.

Comment: Ya me enteré @JesúsFranco y lo tendré en cuenta, que tengas buen día.