# Ediciones sugeridas de etiquetas irrelevantes

Tags: discusión, etiquetas, ediciones-sugeridas

Vengo con un caso que esta sucediendo hace unos días, debido a que me he encontrado un aumento repentino de las ediciones sugeridas, la gran mayoría de ellas que sólo agregan una etiqueta completamente trivial como [archivo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/archivo), [bash](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/bash) u [object](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/object).

Quizás se trate de un caso de cosechar reputación mediante edición, quizás no, pero lo que si puedo asegurar es que son ediciones triviales que no aportan nada al sitio y generan ruido pues cada vez que se edita una pregunta esta aparece en la página inicial, restándole importancia a las ediciones y preguntas nuevas que **SI** requieren atención. Alguna de esas ediciones han sido aprobadas y otras no.

Algunos ejemplos

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13491

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13490

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13456

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13454

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13453

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13452

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13437

La lista continúa y es bastante extensa.

La razón por la que escribo esto es para llamar la atención a la comunidad hacia un comportamiento que es obviamente perjudicial. No estoy tratando de enjuiciar a nadie (por eso no he dicho los usuarios causantes) pero por favor cuando vean una edición así no la aprueben de inmediato, verifiquen que la edición tiene validez y decidan el caso más apropiado, si les parece conveniente háganla ustedes mismos o no la acepten.

Si esto se trata en verdad de cosechar reputación o un error honesto va a detener el problema de una forma u otra.

Una [referencia](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) a tener en cuenta:

> Ediciones pequeñas o triviales no son recomendables - trata de mejorar el post significativamente cuando edites corrigiendo todos los problemas que puedas observar.

Otro [recurso](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) de utilidad

> No utilices las meta-etiquetas en preguntas
>
> Debes re-etiquetar preguntas cuando:
>
> - Estás agregando de esta manera información valiosa a la pregunta
> - Estás sustituyendo etiquetas obscuras o difíciles de entender con etiquetas conocidas y populares que son apropiadas para la pregunta.

**Update**

Quizás sea resultado del post pero ya está comenzando a tener efecto el llamado de alerta. Acabo de rechazar dos ediciones similares en conjunto con la comunidad donde aun se refleja el problema (son tres nuevas las que he encontrado).

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13525

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13528

https://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13524

Comment: Aunque las rechacen, igual seguirán en la lista. Y si han habido ediciones que fueron aprobadas, entonces quizás todas esas ediciones merecen ser revisadas. Me parece que antes de tomar una decisión como "cuando vean una edición así no la aprueben" debería por lo menos invitarse al autor de las ediciones (porque al parecer solo es 1 persona y no varios) y que dé su opinión al respecto para que explique sus razones. Luego de un periodo de gracia que el usuario no responda (que recomiendo sea definido por la comunidad) entonces se proceda con esta decisión, antes no.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza La razón de la recomendación es para tratar de lidiar con el problema de forma pacifica :) quizás el usuario termine cansándose y para mantener la calidad de las preguntas (algunas de ellas muy buenas), pero si, al final es un tema que concierne a toda la comunidad y necesita de la intervención de todos. Mi humilde opinión es que se trata de un caso de cosecha de reputación.

Comment: Yo también detecté (y avisé) esto ayer. Creo que algunas ediciones son justificadas y correctas, aunque de preguntas antiguas. Algunas no. Yo lo trataría como siempre, aunque sea un único usuario está haciendo buenas y malas ediciones. Tenemos que estar atentos y fijarnos bien en si es correcto. Creo que salta a la vista porqué se trata de un único usuario pero si fueran varios no tendríamos problema ni nos daríamos cuenta (seguramente). Yo de momento no haría nada.

Comment: También lo detecté y lo comenté en el chat. En ese momento me contestaron que Luiggi y JuanM ya lo estaban viendo... Muchas fueron irrelevantes, pero hubo algunas buenas ediciones... y debo ser sincero que en ese momento ni pensé en el *bump* que estaba haciendo.

Answer (score 6):

Puede ser cosecha de reputación o puede ser un intento de mejorar el sitio.  Si las ediciones contribuyen al sitio y mejoran el contenido, dejémoslo tal y como esta.

En este caso veo que hay algunas ediciones que sí ayudan y otras que realmente no.  Me gusta la idea que propone Luiggi de pedir al autor que de su opinión y que explique sus razones.  Si se encuentra que solamente se esta editando para aumentar la reputación, podemos poner un alto a esas acciones tal y como lo sugiere devconcept.

Comment: [Esta evidencia](http://i.stack.imgur.com/6AYZa.png) fue la que me llevó a pensar que se trataba de cosecha de reputación. De nuevo no es concluyente y me inclino por una solución pacifica pero definitiva.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza Listo. Me parece que ahora queda mejor la intención de la pregunta

Comment: @devconcept excelente cambio, se lee mejor ahora :)

Comment: @devconcept perfecto, gracias :D.

Comment: @JuanM "*solamente se esta editando para aumentar la reputación, podemos poner un alto*" <-- Y si son buenas ediciones, yo no veo problema en la **[ludificación](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321336/5290909)** de SOes... ¿No lo hacemos todos en mayor o menor medida?

Comment: @Mariano Ese es el problema, que la mayoría no son buenas y el objetivo de dichas ediciones son preguntas buenas que eventualmente pueden ser editadas de nuevo por ser irrelevante la etiqueta. Quizás todos editamos en mayor o menos medida pero lo hacemos para arreglar algo que esté mal, no para agregar un simple cambio que no aporta nada.

Comment: @devconcept Estamos de acuerdo y también coincido con Juan. Sólo me refiero a un punto específico: "**y si son buenas ediciones**"... no creo que el hecho de que esté ludificando sea excusa para ponerle un alto (sí y sólo sí son **buenas** ediciones)

Answer (score 2):

En realidad, además de las etiquetas que se agregan, yo veo un abuso en muchos de los OP que rellenan de etiquetas que no tienen nada que ver con el tema, por ejemplo [esta pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/22784/metodo-get-mas-seguro-evitar-que-el-usuario-introduzca-dato-en-la-url), está etiquetada como javascript, pdo, mysql, html y php, pero solamente toca como filtar o validar un parámetro en PHP.

Yo no tengo experiencia en montones de lenguajes y técnicas y por eso me suscribo por RSS e email a aquellas en las que puedo aportar algo, y es molesto buscar información o preguntas de las que uno puede aprender o compartir, según las etiquetas y encontrar muchas preguntas de poca calidad que solo aparecieron ahí por que las etiquetas se revisan poco.

En mi opinión no es válido que se aprueben ediciones de etiquetas en automático, pero tampoco que se invaliden sin revisar, de hecho cuando no se tiene la suficiente reputación SO dice "tu edición será **revisada** por pares" (énfasis propio). Dice revisada, no solamente votada. Ya en algún momento cuestioné rechazos a ediciones que propuse, [solamente porque le pareció al moderador que no ameritaba mi edición ser revisada](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/767/se-puede-consultar-porqu%C3%A9-fue-rechazada-una-edici%C3%B3n).

Y bueno, en la pregunta enlazada ya propuse quitar las etiquetas sobrantes, espero que ahora sí se revise.

Comment: El caso que comentás es de un usuario relativamente nuevo (pero no lo suficiente para entrar en la cola de revisión de Primeras publicaciones). No podemos pretender que un usuario nuevo sepa cómo etiquetar bien. Tu edición está perfecta, e incluso [fue el autor de la pregunta quien aprobó tu edición](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13835), por lo que debe haberse dado cuenta y seguro le sirve a futuro... El otro caso ya fue discutido y fue sólo un error.